# Can I take my skateboard on Ryanair flight?

Tags: air-travel, ryanair

I have a Penny skateboard (56 cm long) and I was wondering whether I could add it to my luggage. I will fly Ryanair with hand luggage only; 1 bag will go in the plane hold. Can I put my Penny in there?

Comment: When are you flying? Are you affected by Ryanair's new baggage policy? https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage/new-bag-policy-effective-01st-november

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [RyanAir luggage policy](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/terms-and-conditions/termsandconditionsar_696869348):

> 8.4.7 The following items must be checked in: any blunt instrument capable of causing injury, including tennis rackets, baseball and
>   softball bats, clubs or batons - rigid or flexible - e.g. billy clubs,
>   blackjacks (truncheon of leather covered lead with flexible shaft),
>   night sticks & batons, cricket bats, golf clubs, hockey and hurley
>   sticks, lacrosse sticks, kayak and canoe paddles, **skateboards**,
>   billiard, snooker and pool cues, fishing rods, martial arts equipment,
>   e.g. knuckle dusters, clubs, coshes, rice flails, num-chucks,
>   kubatons, kubasaunts.

So as hand luggage, NO. As checked luggage, yes.

Comment: A few years ago I took a flight from Cairns to Melbourne bringing a Penny onboard. The solution was disassembling it: without wheels, it's not a skate anymore ;)